# Non-proprietary solution to fscommand arguments

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, fscommand

I want to pass arguments and execute local batch script from swf. I am using fscommand from which i can call the batch file but i cannot send the arguments. I searched the net a lot and come with some solution.

[SWF Studio](http://www.northcode.com)

[Flash Studio](http://www.multidmedia.com)
and some more

but i need some free or cheap solution. Paying more than $300 for using one feature doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are trying to do this in air, not in browser.

In that case you can include `extendedDesktop` profile support in your app descriptor file like this:

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>
```

And then you can launch your batch file like that:

```
 protected function launchBatchWithParam(batchFileName:String, arguments:Array):void{
    var params:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
    params.arguments = new <String>['/C',File.applicationDirectory.nativePath+'/'+batchFileName];
        for each(var arg:String in arguments){
             params.arguments.push(arg);
        }
    var cmdFile:File =  File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath('C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe');
    params.executable =  cmdFile;
    var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
    process.start(params);                  
}
```

You have to launch your bat with the help of `cmd.exe` as `.bat` files are forbidden because of questionable security concerns of adobe's folks.

Comment: Wouldn't be a bad Idea to do a platform check first.

Comment: I think of using AIR but i am developing it for Linux platform on which ADOBE stop supporting AIR.

Comment: As I know, adobe will support air 2.6 for linux during next 5 years, I guess that's enough for your app. You can use same method to launch your script on linux, but instead of 'cmd' usage you can launch your script directly.